# How do I call plots and tables into an RMarkdown file?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

Let's say I have a dummy plot saved in an R script 'Cars plot.R'

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(data = mpg) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))
```

And then a separate RMarkdown file for a paper I'm writing where I want to call the plot from the 'Cars plot.R' script without any of the code. It looks like this:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "XYZ"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

Then some explanatory text followed by a code chunk which reads:

````
```{r, include = FALSE}
source("Cars plot.R")
```
````

I'm getting that code from the [R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/source-script.html).

I get an error reading:

```
Warning in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :
  cannot open file 'Cars plot.R': No such file or directory
Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) : 
  cannot open the connection
```

Is this an issue with my working directory? I haven't set anything within the scripts. The RMarkdown file is in the structure like this:

`C:/Documents/Project` <- it's in this folder.

And the script is in another folder like this:

`C:/Documents/Project/Codes` <- it's in the codes folder.

Or am I calling it incorrectly using `source()` // need to add more to make the plot visible?

**Edit**:

There was a working directory problem, which putting the .Rmd and .R files into the same folder solved.

Then I needed to assign the ggplot code to an object i.e.

```
plot1 <- ggplot(data = mpg) +    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))
```

Separately, as dcsuka recommended I split out the chunk into two, so the .Rmd file code goes ...

````
```{r, include = FALSE} 
source("Cars plot.R")
```
````

And then in a separate chunk:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE} 
plot1
```
````

The end result being I have the plot in the output without any of the code.

Comment: So -- if I add the .Rmd file and .R script into the same folder, I don't get the error message.

And if I assign the ggplot code to an object I can make it appear in the Rmd file i.e.

`plot1 <- ggplot(data = mpg) + 
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))`

And then ...

`{r, include = TRUE}
source("Cars plot.R")
plot1`

But changing it to TRUE makes all the other code appear with it, when I just want the plot.

Comment: Why not just put the `source()` code in a separate chunk, and use `echo=FALSE` or some other setting to your liking? The main issue here is that you forgot to put the subfolder name in your file path, that's all.

Comment: That worked! So the final code looks like this:     
  
`{r, include = FALSE}
source("Cars plot.R")`
  

and then a separate chunk which has:
  
`{r, echo = FALSE}
plot1`

Comment: If you want to include both code and output generated in your rmarkdown file, you have to write your ggplot code in another Rmarkdown file and then attach it as a child document

Comment: I do not want to include any of the code in the RMarkdown output -- I only want the script outputs (e.g. final plot, table). But I think the issue has been solved per dcsuka's comment (and I documented the changes / success in the edit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a working directory problem, which putting the .Rmd and .R files into the same folder solved.

Then I needed to assign the ggplot code to an object i.e.

`plot1 <- ggplot(data = mpg) +    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = displ, y = hwy))`

Separately, as dcsuka recommended I split out the chunk into two, so the .Rmd file code goes ...

````
```{r, include = FALSE} 
source("Cars plot.R")
```
````

And then in a separate chunk:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE} 
plot1
```
````

The end result being I have the plot in the output without any of the code.